# Use socket to get picture from web Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am doing a project to get the picture from a website(anyone will be OK),and I know that I could use the URL to get it . But I want to know better about the TCP ,so I use the socket to get it . That's all be OK, but the problem is that the data stream I received contain the respond of the HTTP ,and I don't know how to filter it.
Here is my code (just a part of it)

```
        Socket socket = new Socket(netAdress, 80);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write("GET HTTP://" + sources + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.flush()//connect

BufferedOutputStream writeImg = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(adj)); 
            byte[] data = new byte[512];
            int len=0;
            boolean OK=false;
            while ((len=in.read(data))>0) {
                    writeImg.write(data,0,len);
                    writeImg.flush();
            }//receive the data stream
```

and this is what I received,and the picture couldn't open. 
[the detail of the data stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q86k3.png)

If you know how to solved the problem or you have a better idea of get the picture By socket ,please contact me.Thanks.

Comment: Re-implementing HTTP is not a good project to learn about TCP. A better bet is to write the server side yourself with a ServerSocket that serves just the image data and nothing else, and then connect to your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... this is what I received,and the picture couldn't open

Yup.  The response starts with an HTTP response header.

> If you know how to solved the problem ...

Well, this is a hack, and NOT recommended (and it won't work in general!) but the HTTP response header ends with the first `<CR> <NL> <CR> <NL>` sequence (ASCII control codes).  So if you strip off everything up to and including that sequence you should have an image.  (Unless it is compressed, or encoded, or a multi-part, or .....)

> ... or you have a better idea of get the picture.

A better idea is to use the URL.  Seriously.